# User enters URL in Edit text presses onClick button

Tags: android, webview

I want to create an interface with an edittext and a button. The interface will also include a webview.

A user can then enter a url in the edittext and press the button.

This would show the user a view of the webpage in webview.

I understand how to create the layout and the webview. How can I set a function in the onclick method for the button. The function reads the url the user has entered and displays the page.

I would appreciate any answers on how to read a url entered in an edittext and then displayed in a webview.

Thanks

Comment: Chek this link for the button onclick function:
http://knol.google.com/k/thiyagaraaj-m-p/create-simple-browser-using-webview-in/1lfp8o9xxpx13/162#

Answer (score 0):

I believe either the WebView itself has a loadUrl() method, a setWebViewClient() method where the WebViewClient you pass is is an interface you have to implement which then has the loadUrl() method.

So all you need to do, is set an onClick listener to the button, then on click read the text from the EditText (editText.getText().toString()) and then passing that into your WebViewClient.

This guide should help you out alot - [Android Developer Guide - Hello, WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html)

Comment: Thanks, but  if I create an object url = (editText.getText().toString()); and then pass the object url to WebViewClient can I have this in my own webview on the page? As it looks on the developers guide that this will open a browser.

Comment: If you read the entire blog post I think it explains how to load a first page (in this case thevurl from the edittext) but it then goes on to explain how to show links within the web page in the same webview (I.e. stop it from opening in the native browser).